# In my multi store website cart item price is not convert as per selected country's currency

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, default, renderer, cart-items

In my multi store website cart item price is not convert as per selected country's currency.Default currency is USD, When i change my store currency is changed but price display in USD insted of selected currency. Please see the attached screenshot.even symbol is changed but not currency.[image]

Thanks for help in adv.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the currency rates in order to solve this.

```
Goto Admin -> System -> Manage Currency -> Rates
```

You will get all allowed currency there. Then `import` currency and save it.

Comment: already imported.